# send custom email when SQL Server job fails

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent

I have setup a profile and account for sending mail using DatabaseMail. I have a SQL JOB. If the job fails, I receive an Email

Till this point, everything works fine. This is what the email looks like :

```
JOB RUN:        'testjob' was run on 3/7/2014 at 4:50:00 PM
DURATION:       0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
STATUS:         Succeeded
MESSAGES:       The job succeeded.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 10 (s1).  The last step to run was step 1 (run).
```

Now what I want is, if the job fails for any reason, that error message should appear in the email message body.

for example, FK_Constraint error , Conversion errors or any error that caused my sql job to fail.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes this can be done ! Here is an [article](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/have-sql-server-email-you-error-messages-generated-job-failures) that describes how this can be done using stored procs.